# Getting empty values while parsing XML using Pig

Tags: xml, apache-pig

I am getting null values as output while parsing xml file using PIG.
Below is the xml file which i want to parse,

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
    <PhysicalProgress>
    <row>
        <State_Name>Andhra Pradesh</State_Name>
        <District_Name>ADILABAD</District_Name>
        <Project_Objectives_IHHL_BPL>247475</Project_Objectives_IHHL_BPL>
        <Project_Objectives_IHHL_APL>148181</Project_Objectives_IHHL_APL>
        <Project_Objectives_IHHL_TOTAL>395656</Project_Objectives_IHHL_TOTAL>
        <Project_Objectives_SCW>0</Project_Objectives_SCW>
        <Project_Objectives_School_Toilets>4462</Project_Objectives_School_Toilets>
        <Project_Objectives_Anganwadi_Toilets>427</Project_Objectives_Anganwadi_Toilets>
        <Project_Objectives_RSM>10</Project_Objectives_RSM>
        <Project_Objectives_PC>0</Project_Objectives_PC>
        <Project_Performance-IHHL_BPL>176300</Project_Performance-IHHL_BPL>
        <Project_Performance-IHHL_APL>52431</Project_Performance-IHHL_APL>
        <Project_Performance-IHHL_TOTAL>228731</Project_Performance-IHHL_TOTAL>
        <Project_Performance-SCW>0</Project_Performance-SCW>
        <Project_Performance-School_Toilets>4462</Project_Performance-School_Toilets>
        <Project_Performance-Anganwadi_Toilets>427</Project_Performance-Anganwadi_Toilets>
        <Project_Performance-RSM>0</Project_Performance-RSM>
        <Project_Performance-PC>0</Project_Performance-PC>
    </row>
    <row>
        <State_Name>Andhra Pradesh</State_Name>
        <District_Name>ANANTAPUR</District_Name>
        <Project_Objectives_IHHL_BPL>363314</Project_Objectives_IHHL_BPL>
        <Project_Objectives_IHHL_APL>181335</Project_Objectives_IHHL_APL>
        <Project_Objectives_IHHL_TOTAL>544649</Project_Objectives_IHHL_TOTAL>
        <Project_Objectives_SCW>0</Project_Objectives_SCW>
        <Project_Objectives_School_Toilets>3421</Project_Objectives_School_Toilets>
        <Project_Objectives_Anganwadi_Toilets>284</Project_Objectives_Anganwadi_Toilets>
        <Project_Objectives_RSM>10</Project_Objectives_RSM>
        <Project_Objectives_PC>0</Project_Objectives_PC>
        <Project_Performance-IHHL_BPL>366557</Project_Performance-IHHL_BPL>
        <Project_Performance-IHHL_APL>42000</Project_Performance-IHHL_APL>
        <Project_Performance-IHHL_TOTAL>408557</Project_Performance-IHHL_TOTAL>
        <Project_Performance-SCW>0</Project_Performance-SCW>
        <Project_Performance-School_Toilets>4258</Project_Performance-School_Toilets>
        <Project_Performance-Anganwadi_Toilets>302</Project_Performance-Anganwadi_Toilets>
        <Project_Performance-RSM>0</Project_Performance-RSM>
        <Project_Performance-PC>0</Project_Performance-PC>
    </row>
    <row>
        <State_Name>Andhra Pradesh</State_Name>
        <District_Name>CHITTOOR</District_Name>
        <Project_Objectives_IHHL_BPL>296465</Project_Objectives_IHHL_BPL>
        <Project_Objectives_IHHL_APL>236986</Project_Objectives_IHHL_APL>
        <Project_Objectives_IHHL_TOTAL>533451</Project_Objectives_IHHL_TOTAL>
        <Project_Objectives_SCW>0</Project_Objectives_SCW>
        <Project_Objectives_School_Toilets>8171</Project_Objectives_School_Toilets>
        <Project_Objectives_Anganwadi_Toilets>375</Project_Objectives_Anganwadi_Toilets>
        <Project_Objectives_RSM>10</Project_Objectives_RSM>
        <Project_Objectives_PC>0</Project_Objectives_PC>
        <Project_Performance-IHHL_BPL>269750</Project_Performance-IHHL_BPL>
        <Project_Performance-IHHL_APL>190905</Project_Performance-IHHL_APL>
        <Project_Performance-IHHL_TOTAL>460655</Project_Performance-IHHL_TOTAL>
        <Project_Performance-SCW>0</Project_Performance-SCW>
        <Project_Performance-School_Toilets>8171</Project_Performance-School_Toilets>
        <Project_Performance-Anganwadi_Toilets>375</Project_Performance-Anganwadi_Toilets>
        <Project_Performance-RSM>11</Project_Performance-RSM>
        <Project_Performance-PC>0</Project_Performance-PC>
    </row>
</PhysicalProgress>
```

My pig scrip is:

```
 1. REGISTER '/home/training/pig_xml.jar'

 2. xml_input_data = load '/home/training/project/StatewiseDistrictwisePhysicalProgress.xml' using pig.XML.newloader('row') as (x:chararray);

`3. data_from_xml_ip = foreach xml_input_data GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(x,'<row>\\s*<State_Name>(.*)</State_Name>\\s*<District_Name>(.*)</District_Name>\\s*<Project_Objectives_IHHL_BPL>(.*)</Project_Objectives_IHHL_BPL>\\s*<Project_Objectives_IHHL_APL>(.*)</Project_Objectives_IHHL_APL>\\s*<Project_Objectives_IHHL_TOTAL>(.*)</Project_Objectives_IHHL_TOTAL>\\s*<Project_Objectives_SCW>(.*)</Project_Objectives_SCW>\\s*<Project_Objectives_School_Toilets>(.*)</Project_Objectives_School_Toilets>\\s*<Project_Objectives_Anganwadi_Toilets>(.*)</Project_Objectives_Anganwadi_Toilets>\\s*<Project_Objectives_RSM>(.*)</Project_Objectives_RSM>\\s*<Project_Objectives_PC>(.*)</Project_Objectives_PC>\\s*<Project_Performance-IHHL_BPL>(.*)</Project_Performance-IIHL_BPL>\\s*<Project_Performance-IHHL_APL>(.*)</Project_Performance-IHHL_APL>\\s*<Project_Performance-IHHL_TOTAL>(.*)</Project_Performance-IHHL_TOTAL>//s*<Project_Performance-SCW>(.*)</Project_Performance-SCW>\\s*<Project_performance-School_Toilets>(.*)</Project_Performance-School_Toilets>\\s*<Project_Performance-Anganwadi_Toilets>(.*)</Project_Performance-Anganwadi_Toilets>\\s*<Project_Performance-RSM>(.*)</Project_Performance-RSM>\\s*<Project_Performance-PC>(.*)</Project_Performance-PC>\\s*</row>'));`"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ac9pv.png)

Comment: What error message do you get? And please format your pig script for better reading.

Comment: I am not getting any error but getting empty output...like ()()().

Comment: xml_input_data = load '/home/training/project/StatewiseDistrictwisePhysicalProgress.xml' using pig.XML.newloader('row') as (x:chararray);..........

Comment: I have added image of scripts ...could you please check